# Groovy script not getting STRING value from a NUMERIC cell exception when alpha numeric value encounter

Tags: excel, parsing, groovy, apache-poi, soapui

I am trying to read excel data in the Soap Ui using the Groovy script. Everything look good except when script try to get excell cell data then it is throwing Exception. I am not sure how can I use combination of following two:

```
log.info cell.getNumericCellValue()
log.info cell.getStringCellValue()
```

This is how my Excel Data look like:

```
Column1  Column2

USA         1
CANADA      2
FRANCE      3
```

Following are my code:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*


def fs = new FileInputStream("C:\\File\\Book2.xlsx")
def wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs)
def ws = wb.getSheet("Sheet1")
def r = ws.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()


for(def i=0; i<r; i++){

    def row = ws.getRow(i)
    def c = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells()

    for (def j=0; j<c; j++) {

        def cell = row.getCell(j)

         log.info cell.getStringCellValue()
    }
}
```

When I run above code then I am gettig Following exception when my excel contain one column with Alpha value and another column has numeric value:

```
java.lang.illegalStateException:Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell
```

and when I update `log.info cell.getStringCellValue()`   to  `log.info cell.getNumericCellValue()` then it throw following exception:

```
 java.lang.illegalStateException:Cannot get a NUMERIC value from a STRING cell
```

Comment: What happens [if you read the documentation on getting cell values](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents) and check the cell type before fetching?

Comment: After, reading documentation I found the solution to use toString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and find out that this is how we can parse the value:

I just replace `cell.getStringCellValue()` with `cell.toString()`   in the below code and Exception issue is resolved.

Updated code is as below:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*


def fs = new FileInputStream("C:\\File\\Book2.xlsx")
def wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs)
def ws = wb.getSheet("Sheet1")
def r = ws.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()


for(def i=0; i<r; i++){

    def row = ws.getRow(i)
    def c = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells()

    for (def j=0; j<c; j++) {

        def cell = row.getCell(j)

         log.info cell.toString()
    }
}
```